# Except from the use of file extension ...is there any way for automatically detecting the file type

Tags: excel, pdf

I have to write a code for search tool in which the first phase is to distinguish if the file is excel or PDF and then execute the respective part of the code and read the data from the file. the data is then to be used as a search result.   for excel part I have though to use SSIS package to read the data and arrange it in a different spread sheet for result...while for PDF. I am still working on it. but before every thing my code would have to identify the file type .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first few bytes of a file are a "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)" that identifies the file type, for many types of files.

PDF files for example start with `%PDF`, or 0x25 0x50 0x44 0x46.

The magic number for Excel workbooks is [apparently hidden](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=958016) 512 bytes into the file.

There are libraries (`libmagic`) and command line tools (`file`, `mimetype`) that do the job of finding the file type for you without you having to know the intricate details of all file types.